# Does grounding a terminal of a battery make it null?

Tags: batteries, ground

If i ground the negative terminal of the battery, will it make the battery null. Or will i continue to with half its potential.

The circuit is still complete, though the negative terminal is grounded.

Answer (score 2):

"Ground" is generally just the point in the circuit that we choose to call "Zero Volts".  It has no magic properties.

If you ground either terminal of a battery (but NOT both at once!!) you will not change the voltage produced by the battery from the voltage produced without a ground.

Answer (score 1):

A battery does not generate potential. It generates a potential difference across its terminals. Even if you fix the voltage of the one of the terminals of a battery, the battery will ensure that the potential of the other point is such that the potential difference across the terminals is the rated value of the battery (ignoring its internal resistance).

For example, if you ground (set to 0V) the negative terminal of a 9V battery, the potential of the positive terminal would be +9V. Hence the potential difference across the terminals of the battery would be still 9V. Grounding a point in a circuit only ensures that the potential of that point is equal to the potential of the ground and has no effect on the circuit.